# I'm trying to install postgresql by using brew but it cannot find Python.h

Tags: python, macos, postgresql, homebrew

I tried to install postgresql by using brew and the result was

```
checking for libperl... yes
checking Python.h usability... no
checking Python.h presence... no
checking for Python.h... no
configure: error: header file <Python.h> is required for Python
```

After this error I installed Python and it said:

```
brew install python
Warning: python-2.7.5 already installed, it's just not linked
```

what I need to do?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell Homebrew to link Python:

```
$ brew link python
```

Before you do that, it's just installed somewhere under `/usr/local/Cellar` but not linked to `/usr/local/bin` (e.g. `/usr/local/bin/python`) and friends.

The reason this situation happened is that Python seems to have been installed only as a dependency, but the installation of the requested package (PostgreSQL) failed, so its dependencies were left installed but not linked (i.e. activated).